# Example of resource staking from contract

Tags: smart-contract

I'm looking for any relevant code example or documentation describing how to make contract stake resources for some account. I'm aware of `delegatebw` function of `cleos` however, I need the following contract to stake 1 EOS for the users account CPU (or NET) whenever the user is calling `ask()`

```cpp
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract("resource_delegating")]] resource_delegating : public eosio::contract {

public:
  using contract::contract;

  resource_delegating(name receiver, name code,  datastream<const char*> ds): contract(receiver, code, ds) {}

  [[eosio::action]]
  void ask(name user) {
    require_auth( user );
    delegate_resources( user );
  }

private:

  void delegate_resources(name user){

    action(

      // What code should be here?

      //permission level
      //name1
      //name2
      //memo
    ).send();
  }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH( resource_delegating, (ask))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would fill this part of the code in with the relevant action for delegatebw:

```
    eosio::asset quantity(1,eosio::symbol("EOS",4));
    action(
      eosio::permission_level(eosio::name(get_self()), eosio::name("active")), 
      eosio::name("eosio"), eosio::name("delegatebw"), 
      std::tuple(get_self(), user, quantity, quantity, false)
    ).send();
```